# react router loads both components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am programming a simple Login System and if i want to get myself registered, both components get loaded into the App Component.

My Code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
         <div className="row">
            <Header/>
            <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
              <div>
                <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
              </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
<Route path="/" component={Login}/>
```

To

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
```

You can also use the `Switch` component to always ensure that only one component is rendered, though be careful with the order. In this case it would be something like this:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
  </Switch>
```